# Is there a name for this potential property of a Category involving initial and final objects.

Tags: category-theory, terminology

I am wondering whether there is an established term for categories $C$ that satisfy one or both of the following properties $\forall X\in{Obj(C)}$

P1) If $I$ is an initial object in $C$, then $Hom_{C}(I,X)$ is also initial in $C$.

P2) If $F$ is a final object in $C$, then $Hom_{C}(X,F)$ is also final in $C$.

If not, can you point me in the direction of a reference for categories satisfying similar properties?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by something like $Hom_{C}(I,X)$?  Normally that would be a set, not an object of $C$.

Comment: Is this a category with internal hom?

Comment: If $[-,=]\equiv\text{Hom}_C(-,=)$ is a monoidal closure, meaning $X\otimes(-)\dashv[X,-]$ then $[X,1]\cong 1$. If it is the monoidal operation is symmetric then $[0,X]\cong 1$ because $[-,X]^{op}\dashv[-,X]$, and so will only be the initial object if $1\cong 0$.